# Resizing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a task in jQuery (a red box moving left and right) and I have a problem which is when resizing the box continue to the old width.

Here is my code:

```js
var stp = 100;
$(document).ready(function() {
  move();
});

function move() {
  $("div").animate({
    left: "+=" + stp + "px"
  }, {
    step: function() {
      var windowSize = window.innerWidth;
      if ($("div").offset().left >= windowSize - 160) {
        stp = -100;
        $("div").parent().css({
          position: 'relative'
        });
        $("div").css({
          position: 'absolute',
          left: windowSize - 100
        });
      }
      if ($("div").offset().left <= 40)
        stp = 100;
    },
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 1000,
    complete: move
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rectStyle.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="motionJQuery.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="rect"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make the box go from left to right and appears when resizing ?

Comment: `How to make the box go from left to right and appears when resizing ?` no sense this sentence makes

Comment: I don't see where you do resizing in your code... or I did not understood your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.width()` to get the width of  the red box.

For example change if condition from:

```
if ($("div").offset().left >= windowSize - 160)
```

to:

```
if ($("div").offset().left >= windowSize - ($("div").width() + 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean to interactively use the resized container to adapt to current motion?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  move(1);
});

function move( direction ) {
  var own_width = $('#rect').width();
  $({x:0}).animate({x:1}, {
    step: function(percent) {
      let parent_width = $('#rect').parent().width();
      let progress_in_px;
      if( direction == 1 ) {
        progress_in_px = (parent_width -own_width) *percent;
      } else  {
        progress_in_px = (parent_width -own_width) *(1-percent);
      }
      $('#rect').css('left', progress_in_px);
    },
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 1000,
    complete: function() { move(direction*(-1)) }
  });
}
```

```css
div#rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

div.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="rect"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
      <b>Resize me</b>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```